# How do you hide a button in Swift Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode8

I need help on how to hide a button in Swift I have tried to use

```
button.hide = true
```

and

```
button.isHidden = true
```

neither of these work for me. I would be gratefully appreciated if you can help. Thank you.

Comment: Also the error is saying this "value of type'(Any) -> ()' has no member 'isHidden'"

Comment: Please post more code showing how you instantiate the button and where and how you are setting it to be hidden

Answer (score 0):

When you add a button in storyboard and connect its outlet, you should choose type as UIButton.

[image: Check the image]